# Opening Terminal.app with subprocess.Popen breaks conda in macOS

Tags: python, subprocess, conda

I am using macOS. If I kill `Terminal.app` and then from a Python script I call

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen('open -a Terminal.app', shell=True)
```

Then the Terminal will open without conda working, that is, if I type `conda` in the programmatically opened terminal, then I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/home_folder/miniconda3/bin/conda", line 12, in <module>
    from conda.cli import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'conda'
```

If I kill again the Terminal, then I open it the normal way, and then I close the only window but not killing the process (that is using `CMD+W` instead of `CMD+Q`), then if I run the script above, a new terminal window will open with conda properly working.

A similiar problem that I think is related to this is that if I open `PyCharm` analogously as above, then PyCharm is broken, I hope that a solution for the Terminal problem will be easily extended also to that case, otherwise I will create another question later.

(I am using virtualenv for this script, not sure it helps)

Comment: How is conda activated in your shell init scripts? Are you using `.profile`, `.bashrc`, etc?

Comment: I used `conda init zsh`, which adds the usual automatic conda configuration in `~/.zshrc` [I pasted it here](https://pastebin.com/0hQgctt7). I put a echo message in '~/.zshrc` and it is printed by the subprocess.